# Use of “Would be” vs. “Is”

Tags: present-tense, conditionals

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> If you do this exercise badly, that would be a violation.

Versus:

> If you do this exercise badly, it is a violation.

Comment: I can't understand the context of the sentence. What exercise? A violation of what?

Comment: It’s a violation as if it were a contest in which you need to perform exercises in good form.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a difference in tense.

> Doing this is a violation.

Here we’re simply stating the “rules” (present tense). In some context, doing something is a violation (against the “rules”).

> Doing this would be a violation.

Here we paint a hypothetical picture of the thing having already been done, and state that it would be/would have been a violation (past tense).